# Trying to make the link in a drop-down change the hero image in different div

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to use my navigation as a way to display image in the header.
Before Iv used frist child:hover to do this but with the addition of a drop down menu and using css grid to make the page layout the link are too nested for this to work.

Is there any other was to do this?

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Hi, am a Graphic Designer</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><h3><a>About Me</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a>Get in Touch</a></h3></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><h3><a href="#Work">View Some of My Work</a></h3>
          <ul class="dropdown-content">
              <li><h3><a href="#" class="img1">link1<!--when hover have BG of hero-image change--></a></h3></li>
              <li><h3><a href="#" class="img2">link2<!--when hover have BG of hero-image change--></a></h3></li>
              <li><h3><a href="#" class="img3">link3<!--when hover have BG of hero-image change--></a></h3></li>
              <li><h3><a href="#" class="img4">link4<!--when hover have BG of hero-image change--></a></h3></li>
              <li><h3><a href="#" class="img5">link5<!--when hover have BG of hero-image change--></a></h3></li>
              <li><h3><a href="#" class="img6">link6<!--when hover have BG of hero-image change--></a></h3></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-image" id="hero-image"> <!--have the BG of this div change depending on whicht link you are hovered hon in the dropdown menu --> </div>
</div>
```

Code pen link. https://codepen.io/Ok_Donki/pen/poLJjbb

Comment: It's so unclear what you are trying to acheive

Comment: You could use JavaScript utilizing `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`  events to toggle CSS classes for the hero image. Those class of course would include different BG each.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.